# Подробности взаимодействия ключевого слова synchronized и объекта монитора

Tags: java, многопоточность

Есть некоторые подробности в взаимодействии ключевого слова `synchronized` и объекта монитора которые я хотел бы прояснить:

**Пример №1 :**

```
void increment() {
    synchronized (this) {
        ...
    }
}

void someMethod() {...}
```

**Вопрос 1** : Если есть 2 потока один из которых вошел в метод  `increment()` озночает ли это что данный объект заблокирован полностью записью `synchronized (this)`, и никакой другой поток использовать этот объект не сможет, в том числе и метод `void someMethod()` не смотря на то, что этот метод не как не синхронизирован?

**Пример №2 :**

```
private final Object lock = new Object();

private void m1() {
    synchronized (this) {
        ...
    }
}

private void m2() {
    synchronized (lock) {
        ...
    }
}
```

**Вопрос 2** : я правильно понимаю что при вызове `m1()` одним потоком, весь объект станет недоступен в том числе и `m2()`. А если вызвать с начала `m2()` то недоступна станет только критическая секция внутри него, а что будет если вызвать в этот момент `m1()`? Этот поток просто встанет в очередь так как `lock` занят в то время как является частью `this` и пока `lock` не будет отпущен блокировка по `this` не возможна?

**Пример №3 :**

```
private final Object monitor = new Object();

private void method() {
    synchronized (monitor) {
        ...
    }
}
```

**Вопрос 3** : как правильно понимать взаимодействие объекта `monitor` и критической секции? `monitor` блокируется зашедшим в критическую секцию потоком, а остальные стоящие в очереди ждут пока монитор отпустит, потому что без него войти не могут? Или можно сказать что пока монитор занят он блокирует потоки которые стоят на входе в критическую секцию? То есть кто кого блокирует?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Если есть 2 потока один из которых вошел в метод  increment() озночает ли это что данный объект заблокирован полностью записью synchronized (this), и никакой другой поток использовать этот объект не сможет, в том числе и метод void someMethod() не смотря на то, что этот метод не как не синхронизирован?

Нет, второй метод можно будет беспроблемно вызывать. Только synchronized-метод будет иметь какое-либо взаимодействие с локом, иначе бы единственный synchronized-метод превращал бы весь в класс в фабрику блокировок, и какой-нибудь безобидный вызов `isRunning()` мог бы затягиватсья на долгие секунды.

> Вопрос 2 : я правильно понимаю что при вызове m1() одним потоком, весь объект станет недоступен в том числе и m2(). А если вызвать с начала m2() то недоступна станет только критическая секция внутри него, а что будет если вызвать в этот момент m1()? Этот поток просто встанет в очередь так как lock занят в то время как является частью this и пока lock не будет отпущен блокировка по this не возможна?

Нет, вот если бы m2 был объявлен как synchronized, тогда бы VM остановилась при входе в m2 до тех пор, пока synchronized-блок в m1 не завершится. Сами же объекты (lock и this) никак не взаимосвязаны, поэтому synchronized-версия m2 представляла бы просто две вложенных невзаимосвязанных блокировки.

> Вопрос 3 : как правильно понимать взаимодействие объекта monitor и критической секции? monitor блокируется зашедшим в критическую секцию потоком, а остальные стоящие в очереди ждут пока монитор отпустит, потому что без него войти не могут? Или можно сказать что пока монитор занят он блокирует потоки которые стоят на входе в критическую секцию? То есть кто кого блокирует?

Блокируются потоки при попытке захватить intrinsic lock объекта. Так как этот лок уже взят, поток, вызывающий внутренний функционал захвата лока, переводится виртуальной машиной или ОС (здесь требуется уточнение кого-то более опытного) в спящее состояние до тех пор, пока лок не станет свободен и VM не сможет передать его ожидающему потоку. Сам лок может быть взят  каким-то потоком либо свободен, сам по себе он никаких действий не предпринимает.

```
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import static java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.allOf;
import static java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completedFuture;

public class EntryPoint {

    interface Callable {
        void call() throws Exception;
    }

    private static CompletableFuture<Void> run(Callable callable) {
        return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            try {
                callable.call();
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                System.out.println("Unexpected exception: ");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Synchy synchy = new Synchy();
        CompletableFuture synchronizer = completedFuture(null)
                .thenCompose(v -> allOf(run(synchy::t1m1), run(synchy::t1m2)))
                .thenCompose(v -> allOf(run(synchy::t2m1), run(synchy::t2m2)))
                .thenCompose(v -> allOf(run(synchy::t3m1), run(synchy::t3m2)));
        synchronizer.get();
    }

    private static class Synchy {
        private final Object lock = new Object();

        public void t1m1() throws Exception {
            synchronized (this) {
                System.out.println("t1m1: Entered synchronized block");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println("t1m1: Leaving synchronized block");
            }
        }
        public void t1m2() throws Exception {
            Thread.sleep(10);
            System.out.println("Shouting from t1m2");
        }

        public void t2m1() throws Exception {
            synchronized (this) {
                System.out.println("t2m1: Entered synchronized block");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println("t2m1: Leaving synchronized block");
            }
        }

        public void t2m2() throws Exception {
            Thread.sleep(100);
            synchronized (lock) {
                System.out.println("t2m2: Entered synchronized block");
                Thread.sleep(100);
                System.out.println("t2m2: Leaving synchronized block");
            }
        }

        public void t3m1() throws Exception {
            synchronized (this) {
                System.out.println("t3m1: Entered synchronized block");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println("t3m1: Leaving synchronized block");
            }
        }

        public synchronized void t3m2() throws Exception {
            Thread.sleep(100);
            synchronized (lock) {
                System.out.println("t3m2: Entered synchronized block");
                Thread.sleep(100);
                System.out.println("t3m2: Leaving synchronized block");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

вывод:

```
t1m1: Entered synchronized block
Shouting from t1m2 // t1m2 успешно выполнился, пока t1m1 все еще был в synchronized-блоке
t1m1: Leaving synchronized block
t2m1: Entered synchronized block
t2m2: Entered synchronized block // t2m2 успешно зашел в synchronized-блок, когда t2m1 тоже находился в synchronized-блоке
t2m2: Leaving synchronized block
t2m1: Leaving synchronized block
t3m1: Entered synchronized block
t3m1: Leaving synchronized block
t3m2: Entered synchronized block // t3m2 смог зайти в synchronized-блок только после того, как t3m1 освободил лок объекта this
t3m2: Leaving synchronized block
```